# How to add Actions to MACOS FileProvider API and use them in the Code?

Tags: macos, fileprovider-extension

I'm working on a macOS project that involves the FileProvider API. I would like to add custom actions to the items provided by the FileProvider and use them in my code. How can I achieve this?

Specifically, I want to know:

How can I add actions to the macOS FileProvider API?
How can I define and customize these actions?
How can I handle the execution of the selected actions in my code?
How can I access and use these actions in my code?
I've already created a File Provider extension target in my Xcode project and implemented the necessary protocols. I just need guidance on how to add and utilize actions with the FileProvider API.

I would appreciate any example code or step-by-step instructions to help me understand and implement this functionality. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileproviderui/adding_actions_to_the_context_menu

and you can use it like this using performaction()

```
 func performAction(identifier actionIdentifier: NSFileProviderExtensionActionIdentifier, 
 onItemsWithIdentifiers itemIdentifiers: [NSFileProviderItemIdentifier], 
 completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) -> Progress {
        switch actionIdentifier.rawValue {

}

}
```